# error in mounting drive on Ubuntu Mate terminal

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ubuntu-mate, mate-terminal

I am trying to access files in the partition named "Envision" from the Ubuntu Mate terminal.

The output of

```
df -h
```

is as follows

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            855M     0  855M   0% /dev
tmpfs           175M  5.9M  169M   4% /run
/dev/sda2        96G   28G   63G  31% /
tmpfs           874M  1.6M  873M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           874M     0  874M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           175M   40K  175M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1        30G   28G  2.1G  93% /media/snow/SanDisk-32GB
/dev/sda3       126G  115G   12G  91% /media/snow/Envision
/dev/sda6        76G   63G   13G  84% /media/snow/Softwares
```

When I try to mount hard disk partition named "Envision", using

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3
```

I get the following output

```
mount: can't find /dev/sda3 in /etc/fstab
```

Am I missing out on something? Kindly help.

Comment: Looks to me like `/dev/sda3` is already mounted at `/media/snow/Envision`. Try `ls -al /media/snow/Envision` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things happening here. You want to mount the drive `/dev/sda3` to access the files in `Envision`.

`df -h` is reporting that `/dev/sda3` is already mounted at `/media/snow/Envision`, but you tried anyway with the command `sudo mount /dev/sda3`.

The correct format for `mount` is (you missed the `<mountpoint>` part):

```
sudo mount /dev/<drive> /<mountpoint>
```

Placing `sudo` in front is only a requirement unless you are currently the `root` user.

The reason `sudo mount /dev/sda3` spat out that particular error message is because (at a guess) you did not include any details about `/dev/sda3` in `/etc/fstab`, which `mount` will look in if the mount point is missing.

BTW, even if the drive is mounted at one point, you can re-mount at another point (so that one drive is mounted in two locations) but personally I do not recommend this.

Edit:

If this drive is to be mounted only a few times (like an external drive) then you can do this:

```
sudo mkdir /Envision
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /Envision
```

You can then access the drive contents at `/Envision`. For example:

```
ls -al /Envision
```

Alternatively if you are keeping this drive in your system all the time you can edit `/etc/fstab` and then the drive will be found when you reboot the system (or if you do `sudo mount -a`). To add the drive to `/etc/fstab`

First get the UUID or universally unique identifier like so:

```
sudo blkid
```

The output will be something like:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="85ec7b1a-7d67-47f1-bcc9-4c4f4ed370b5" TYPE="ext4"
```

The important part is the `UUID="85ec7b1a-7d67-47f1-bcc9-4c4f4ed370b5"` BUT you also need to make sure you get the `TYPE` correct.

Next, open `/etc/fstab` in a text editor as `root`. I use `vim`, so I do:

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

Now add a line with the drive details. Using my example above:

```
UUID=85ec7b1a-7d67-47f1-bcc9-4c4f4ed370b5 /Envision ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

If the drive type is `ntfs` you would replace `ext4` with `nfs` BUT I'm not 100% sure what the other options would be. You would need to check them.

Save the file and type `sudo mount -a` and if there are no issues your drive will be mounted and will be mounted on the next reboot as well.

Comment: "BTW, even if the drive is mounted at one point, you can re-mount at another point." Can the mount point be any arbitrary location where I want to mount the drive onto? Kindly help with this.

Comment: "The reason sudo mount /dev/sda3 spat out that particular error message is because (at a guess) you did not include any details about /dev/sda3 in /etc/fstab, which mount will look in if the mount point is missing." What information about /dev/sda3 needs to be put in /etc/fstab. Could you please help me with this

Comment: See edited post. Please remove at least one of the duplicate comments above.